# my if statement in my while loop does not activate on its own in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

okay so there's this weird glitch I am having in Java, and I have solved the issue but I don't understand why the issue is there to begin with.  So I have a while loop and the loop is constantly waiting for my string variable "input" to change, and the input changes when the enter key is hit.  the while loop continues to loop while the boolean "waiting" is true.  so the while loop is constantly looping with a single if-else statement in it, the if statement says that if "input" is still "" then "waiting" continues to equal true.  else, waiting = false.  However while this is looping, I can enter text into the field that input will read from and hit enter, but when I do nothing happens.  unless I have some other code in my my while loop.  Any other code that seems to output text in some way fixes this issue and I don't understand why.  I'll show the non-working code and an example of working code.

not working

```
boolean waiting = true;
while(waiting)
{
    if(input.equals(""))
        waiting = true;
    else
        waiting = false;
    //System.out.println("waiting");
}
```

working

```
boolean waiting = true;
while(waiting)
{
    if(input.equals(""))
        waiting = true;
    else
        waiting = false;
    System.out.println("waiting");
}
```

I don't understand why this fixes this issue, it adds no functionality to the program i just used it to see if the loop was looping which it was and suddenly the overall problem went away, why does this fix this?

Comment: try putting blocks on your if else, if(condition){code}else{morecode}

Comment: There is not enough context to answer. What is `input`, how is it declared? What writes to it? It is _possible_ that this is from Thread starvation; the first non-working busy-loops furiously doing nothing, and whatever writes to `input` never gets a chance to run — but the second writes output, which can make the thread yield and the other thread gets its chance to change the value of input. Try replacing your println with `Thread.currentThread().yield();`

Comment: There is nothing to fix. The code works as it should assuming that the `input` variable is empty (Null String). Again, this is assuming since you provide no clue as to what `input` is used for or how it is filled. Both code versions do the very same thing.

Comment: @StephenP what you said worked, I posted an answer that also provides more context to the code, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

okay so someone who commented was able to give me a workable solution and they explained the glitch as well.  Stephen P suggested it might be Thread starvation and he recommended replacing my print statement with

```
Thread.currentThread().yield();
```

and that fixed the problem, thank you Stephen P for the help.

For those asking for context previously in the program "input" was set to "" so it is not null, and when the enter key gets pressed there is this code:

```
public helloWorld(){
    jta.setEditable(false);
    stats.setEditable(false);
    add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(stats, BorderLayout.EAST);
    stats.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10)));
    jta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10)));
    jtf.setFont(jtf.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20f));
    jtf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
    
    jta.setText("The game is now beginning\n"
            + "What name do you want to give your character?\n");
    stats.setText("");
    
    jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            input = jtf.getText();
            //ystem.out.println("heard");
        }
    });
}
```

where jtf is a java text field that a user input text into.  That is utilizied in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            frame = new helloWorld();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            //System.out.println("listening");
        }
    });

    input = "";
    playGame();
}
```

it did end up being thread stravation, it was just that the loop was running too fast and so input never had a chance to get updated.  Thank you again Stephen P

also the constructor is called hello world cause I just have a hello world file constantly ready to go as a test file, yes I know it looks out of place I am sorry.  And I should have provided more context up front I am sorry.

Comment: Glad you figured it out — but now you should research more; there are better ways to react to a Swing JTextField changing(\*), and aside from that busy-loops are generally A Bad Thing™ -- they eat CPU cycles for lunch ... (\*) (I haven't done Swing for ages, or I'd suggest something. [EventListener](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_event_listeners.htm)? [wait and notify](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)? )

Comment: @StephenP this program originally looked vastly different, it didn't have any loops, but that system was cluttered and messy and far worse than what this is so far.  I will look into some other options as this still isn't very good.